# CSS Spritesheets and picture marker symbols in the AGS Javascript API

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm working on improving the load performance of a large ArcGIS Javascript application, and one area where we can have trouble is that there is a visible delay between putting a graphic with a PictureMarkerSymbol on the map and seeing the symbol load, particularly when there are a large number of features with various symbols.

Is there a way to pull picture marker symbols or something similar from a CSS spritesheet to get all of the images loaded as a group?

Answer (score 2):

We are using two ways to improve that:
1. Instead of use picture symbols in mxd, you can publish the service without any simbology and then load a picture directly inside the javascript code
2. Use the 'cluster' functionality to group symbols depending on the scale

You can find a sample here:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html

Regards,
Evemar